# Text-transform won't change as well as the font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a WordPress site here: http://www.iliveaccountable.com/

That I want to change the first element "iLiveAccountable" to font family to CaviarDreams_Italic.ttf and change the text-transform into "none" so that it will follow the exact text.

[image]

I place all my fonts on a folder and added this code on my style.css sheet and tried to play it using the inspect element since I am only targeting the first element in the navigation:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Caviar Dreams;
    src: url(http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/themes/unicon/fonts/CaviarDreams_Italic.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
}


li#menu-item-15113{
text-transform: none;
font-family: Caviar Dreams;
}
```

For some reason I can't still change the font family as well as the text-transform. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? I really need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
#menu-item-15113 a{
text-transform: none;
font-family: Caviar Dreams !important;
}
```

The "a" tag has its own font which is "Montserrat" thats why you can't change them via "li" tag only.

Comment: It works however the text-transform did not. Can you check what's hindering me from not changing the text to the normal state?

Comment: just add !important in the text-transform. it did't work because the #navigation make it uppercase.

Comment: how about the "italic"? I added important but it did not work?

Comment: yeah I know but using font-style: normal !important; did not work.